# Injector Error with pikaday-angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pikaday

I am using pikaday directive with my project. But It returns error.
Error: $injector:modulerr
Module Error
Failed to instantiate module [iba.controlls.ui] due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.0/$injector/modulerr?p0=p...)
    at Error (native)
    at http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:6:416
    at http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:40:60
    at n (http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:135)
    at http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:304
    at n (http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:7:355)
    at g (http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:39:135)
    at fb (http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:43:164)
    at Ac.c (http://localhost:1203/Scripts/angular.min.js:20:449

How to fix it.?

my code is

```
angular.module('[iba.controlls.ui]', ['ui.bootstrap', '[iba.dataservice.data]', '[iba.services.ui]','ngSanitize','pikaday']);
```

Comment: Use the non-minified angular.js and see what the error is

Comment: @devqon the error : Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'pikaday' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument

Comment: Then you probably forgot to include the script before your `angular.module()` script